# Dojo build AT run time

Tags: javascript, build, dojo

I am building several dojo custom builds using profiles,I found that extremely useful, but it takes literally one hour to create my builds. I would like that my application would "fetch" only what needed.
Here is my question:

Is it possible to have profiles at run time?

Let's say my profile (called `my.test.profile`) has `dojo.data`,

```
dojo.ItemFileWriteStore
```

E.g. Instead of calling

```
dojo.require("dojo.data") dojo.require(dojo.ItemFileWriteStore)
```

->

```
dojo.require("my.test.profile")
```

Is this possible to do in dojo?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an intermediate [layer](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/) file to bundle up requires:

```
//mylayer.js
dojo.provide('mylayer');
dojo.require(...);
dojo.require(...);
//...
```

So you can require only it instead of that bunch of stuff

```
//my_other_file.js
dojo.erquire('mylayer');
```

It is also possible to use the layerDependencies settings on the profile to make it so that the code is compiled into seperate layers instead of just a single blob (this if you want to be able to lazy-load a part that is not often used)

I don't know how to make the build process faster or what is the propper way to do this with the new AMD modules though.

Comment: Hi! thanks for replying, I will definitively try that! I was looking at the LayerDependencies, but that requires to compile the build and it might be too long, I am looking something that could cut the build/dependencies at run time.